# Why should we avoid nested blocks of code to be empty?

Tags: java, pmd

Most of the time a block of code is empty when a piece of code is really missing. 
So such empty block must be either filled or removed. What is the reason to do so?

How does leaving the block empty affect the compilation?

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i< 4; i++) 
{

}


try 
{

}


catch (Exception e) 
{

}
```

Comment: what do you mean about "So such empty block must be either filled or removed"? cuz Java compiler never complains about any empty block at all as far as I know

Comment: note the PMD tag. this is referring to this code style tool.

Comment: @Kick Yes..Though Java compiler doesn't complain., According to PMD it is not advisable to do so..Can anyone explain why?

Comment: @SlipperySeal what is PMD?

Comment: From the sourceforge site: "PMD is a source code analyzer. It finds common programming flaws like unused variables, empty catch blocks, unnecessary object creation, and so forth."

Answer (score 3):

In most cases PMD is alerting you to the fact that your empty block does nothing. Why create a for loop or try block which does nothing? In the case of the Exception catch though, it's technically "valid" to catch an Exception and do nothing in the block, but most of the time it causes problems. PMD wants you to act on this exception.

If the Exception doesn't get acted on you can get more errors down the track as a knock on effect of the first problem which occurred. Example: you catch an IOException but then "eat" the exception and don't let the rest of the program know there was an error.

Comment: I agree to your point..But there is certainly some more effort needed by the compiler in this case rather than going to the next lines of the code..There must be a specific reason why PMD suggests that..Is the time consumption of the compiler the only reason??

Comment: it's nothing to do with performance. As per their own decription." It finds common programming flaws like unused variables, empty catch blocks, unnecessary object creation, and so forth". An empty catch block is a bug (according to PMD anyway). And most of the time it is. Note that with PMD you can suppress errors using annotations if you are sure you wanted to do it that way.

Comment: Ok.Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: You are using PMD to help you find problems with your code. And it's telling you :) It's a very common scenario with Java where someone puts a catch around some code to "fix it". The Exception doesn't get acted on then you get more errors down the track as a knock on effect of the first problem which occurred. Example: you catch an IOException but then "eat" the exception and don't let the rest of the program know there was an error.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the catch block. But could you cite any advantages / disadvantages of leaving the FOR block empty?

Comment: in your above example. you create a loop which counts 0 to 4 in 'i' but does nothing with i at any stage. What does that loop 'do'? Nothing. But, you can write for loops which effect other variables or call methods. In this case, you would use a semicolon instead of brackets. for (x=0;something();x<blah());  The disadvantage of an empty block is that it has no advantage. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks @SlipperySeal.That sounds convincing enough.